# Are we allowed to use the Genizah (Shaimos) to bury fingernails and toenails?

Tags: hands-fingers, genizah-storage, nail-cutting

If it's considered the act of the Righteous to bury our fingernails and toenails, can we fulfill this by placing them in the Genizah with the Shaimos, or must we dig a hole and bury them ourselves?